# How to insert a row inside another row in an Angular table?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to add a row inside another in an Angular table, so that each sector of each area appears individually in each row.

With the code I'm using I get close to the expected result, but the line isn't complete.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="server" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- Column Areas -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="areas">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Areas</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let area">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let sector of area.sectors">
          {{ area.name }}
      <td mat-cell></td>
        </ng-container>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

  <!-- Column Sectors -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="sectors">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Sectors</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let area">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let sector of area.sectors">
        * {{ sectors.sectors }} <br /><br />
      </ng-container>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Column Activities -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="activities">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Activities</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let area">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let sector of area.sectors">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let activity of sector.activities">
          * {{ activity.activity }} <br /><br />
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Column Deadlines -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="deadlines">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Deadlines</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let area">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let sector of area.sectors">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let activity of sector.activities">
          {{ activity.deadline}} days<br /><br />
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns;"></tr>

</table>
```

The result I'm getting is this:

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luUcX.png)

Answer (score 0):

You has:

```
 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let area">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let sector of area.sectors">
          {{ area.name }}
          <td mat-cell></td>
        </ng-container>
 </td>
```

I imagine should be

```
 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let area">
       {{ area.name }}
 </td>
```